# I can't draw continuous lines on another image using PAN GESTURE

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7, uipangesturerecognizer

The code which I used to draw on images is as given below, I am using **panGesture** to find where the user touches. Now when I use this code *the lines the user draws comes as points when i am moving my hands over the image very fast.*

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((self.thatsMyImage.frame.size), NO, 0.0);
    [self.selfieImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,self.thatsMyImage.frame.size.width, self.thatsMyImage.frame.size.height)];
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), from.x, from.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), to.x , to.y);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0f);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(to.x, to.y,10,10));

CGContextSetFillColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]));
CGContextFillPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

self.thatsMyImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This is the method which is being called when panGesture is detected.

```
-(void)freeFormDrawing:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    CGPoint p = [gesture locationInView:self.selfieImage];
    CGPoint startPoint = lastPoint;
    lastPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.selfieImage];

    [self drawLineFrom:startPoint endPoint:p];

}
if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
//        lastPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.selfieImage];
    }
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how can i do free-form (Doodle) on images with smooth lines and curves? Thanks in advance and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

I had implemented the same what I had was that I was adding a transparent UIImageView above the UIImageView that had my UIImage I wanted to draw on.

```
UIImageView *drawableView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.drawImageView.bounds];
drawableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(drawingViewDidPan:)];
[drawableView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Then when the user panned on the UIImageView I would call this function

```
- (void)drawingViewDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
  CGPoint currentDraggingPosition = [sender locationInView:drawableView];

  if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
      prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
  }

  if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
      [self drawLine:prevDraggingPosition to:currentDraggingPosition];
  }
  prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
}
```

Both prevDraggingPosition and currentDraggingPosition are CGPoint.

Then I used the following function to draw line from the prevDraggingPosition to currentDraggingPosition

```
-(void)drawLine:(CGPoint)from to:(CGPoint)to
{
  @autoreleasepool {

    CGSize size = drawableView.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [drawableView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    CGFloat strokeWidth = 4.0;
    strokeColor = colorChangeView.backgroundColor;

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    drawableView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  }
}
```

Then finally to get the image with the drawing on it you can build the image by drawing the drawableView image onto your UIImageView that has your image like this.

```
- (UIImage*)buildImage
{
  @autoreleasepool {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImageSize, NO, self.drawImageView.image.scale);

    [self.drawImageView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [drawableView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, originalImageSize.width, originalImageSize.height)];

    UIImage *tmp = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return tmp;
  }
}
```

Where originalImageSize is the size of your image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash Dadhich, even if i had to make some modification I've met with my need.